# Close modal in specific situations bootstrap4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to disable modal. if there're more than 1 checkboxes that checked and allow modal when only 1 checkboxes that checked. At now, when i clicked button modal it just pop-up without error. but, it just allow always.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check-all">
<input type="checkbox" class="check">
<input type="checkbox" class="check">
<input type="checkbox" class="check">

<button id="btn-edit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
    EDIT
</button>
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">TEMPLATE MESSAGE</h5>
                <button id="btn-close" type="button" class="close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="post" action="">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea id="value-message" type="text" class="form-control" name="template-message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <button id="btn-save" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col text-right">
                            <span id="length-message"></span><span> / 160</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

$("btn-edit").click(function(){
  var checkLength = 0;

  for(var i = 0; $('.check').length; i++){
    checkLength += 1;
  }

  if(checkLength > 1){
     $(".modal").on("shown.bs.modal", function(){
       $(".modal").modal("hide");
     });
  }else{
     $(".modal").modal("show");
  }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**FIRST:** `btn-edit` is an ID you should call it with `#btn-edit`

**SECOND:** for getting checked checkboxes length for specific class you should use:

```
$('input:checkbox.check:checked')
```

**THIRD:** You don't need a for loop for this since the code above will give you the amount of checked checkboxes.

**FORTH:** Here is a sample near to your code:

```js
$("#btn-edit").click(function(){
if($('input:checkbox.check:checked').length > 1){
     $(".info").html("More than 1! The modal will not show");
     $(".modal").hide();
}
else if ($('input:checkbox.check:checked').length == 1){
     $(".info").html("ONLY ONE CHECKBOX CHECKED. The modal will show!");
     $(".modal").show();
}
else{
     $(".info").html("No Checkbox checked. The modal will not show!");
     $(".modal").hide();
}   
});
```

```css
.info {
border: 1px solid green;
}
.modal {
margin-top: 5px;
border: 1px solid blue;
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="check-all">
<input type="checkbox" class="check">
<input type="checkbox" class="check">
<input type="checkbox" class="check">

<button id="btn-edit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
    EDIT
</button>
<div class="info">
Check the checkboxes!
</div>
<div class="modal">
I only show if ONLY one checkbox is checked.
</div>
```